# Set UIBarStyle of UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like to set the bar style of a `UIImagePickerController` as following, but the bar is still `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent`. Is it possible to set the bar style of `UIImagePickerController`? Thanks in advance!

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;        
imagePicker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

Edit 1

I can set the tint color through:

```
imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xCC6600);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what worked for me (you need to test the class of the navigationController, not the viewController being presented, and you need to set a non-transparent background color as well it seems)

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([navigationController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]])
    {
        navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is The bar still transparent? Actually i wanna it be opaque.

Comment: It will become opaque once you set the background color to a solid color (eg. black), like in my example

Answer (score 1):

```
imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the change by implementing the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method `navigationController:willShowViewController:`, like this:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
            animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if([viewController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]])
             navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
 }
```

Comment: I tried this method, but still can not set the bar style to UIBarStyleBlack

Comment: Does the method even get called? Does your class conform to `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol, and are you setting the class as delegate to the picker? i,e: `picker.delegate = self`. I don't see it in the code you provided.

Comment: Try it with the `didShow....` method instead. And the viewController isn't a UIImagePickerController class instance in this case if I remember correct.

Comment: if it's not a `UIImagePickerController` class, remove the `isKindOfClass:` check.

Comment: @Ariel is the didShow a method of UIImagePickerController?

Comment: @skram navigationController:willShowViewController: this method get called, the delegate is set.

Comment: @luyuan try removing the `isKindOfClass:` check as someone mentioned it might not be the class.

Comment: No. It's something like - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;

Comment: @skram after removing,         navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack; is get called, but the bar style still be Translucent.

Comment: @Ariel I tried it, but the same. wow, thx for your help, im sleepy. it is 4:19am, good nite all:P

Comment: Try to set the `tintColor` property instead.

Comment: @Ariel the original answer was already edited to reflect the fact that the `tintColor` does indeed work.